# 14.04 sometimes unexpectedly logs me out and closes all programs upon resume from suspend

Tags: 14.04, suspend, logout, resume

What can I provide to help diagnose the issue for potential solutions? I am using a Lenovo Yoga 2 11"

This solution doesn't work: [Logged out on resume from sleep ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/745944/logged-out-on-resume-from-sleep-ubuntu-15-10)

I don't want to break things, so I'll ask...

Would the second solution to this work despite it being for 13.04?
[Any open window and program is gone when I close my laptop lid (Suspend). What should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310423/any-open-window-and-program-is-gone-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid-suspend-what-s)

How about this for 12.04?
[Resume from suspend - all programs are closed 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380024/resume-from-suspend-all-programs-are-closed-12-04)

Apparently the ideas for people on 16.04, 16.10 aren't working. [Resume from suspend close all programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853042/resume-from-suspend-close-all-programs)